# Using 3rd Party shared library on Android with NDK with Untiy3D

Tags: android, plugins, android-ndk

I am trying to make an Android Plugin which uses FMOD for Android, using the NDK (I need this to be native because I am also using a third party open-source C++ library that needs to interact with FMOD, which works fine).
I am able to compile everything with the NDK OK, but when I create my Unity project, I always get a DLLNotFoundException if I am using the FMOD shared lib.
Note that the shared library that I created works fine if I do not include any FMOD calls, so I am pretty sure that the Unity player cannot find the FMOD shared libs.

This is my plugins code:

```
extern "C" {
#endif

    static int mycount = 0;
    int FooTest(){

        unsigned int version;
        FMOD::System* system_;

        //Init
        FMOD_RESULT result = FMOD::System_Create(&system_);
        if (result != FMOD_OK) return -1;

        result = system_->getVersion(&version);
        if (result != FMOD_OK) return -1;

        if (version < FMOD_VERSION)
        {
            //printf("Error!  You are using an old version of FMOD %08x.  This program requires %08x\n", version, FMOD_VERSION);
            return -1;
        }
        result = system_->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);
        if (result != FMOD_OK) return -1;

        return mycount++;
    }


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

If I comment out all the FMOD stuff, the returned count is incremented and shown on screen. Whenever I build with the FMOD calls, I get the "DLLNotFoundException:FooTest"

I included the fmodex.so and fmodexL.so libraries both in my plugins/android directory and in the root of my project, and I have checked that they are present in the lib/armeabi folder of the generated APK.

If anyone is interested I can also post the Android makefiles I use to generate my shared library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .so libs must be included in the root directory of the project for them to be found.